# I'm trying to resize my tabcontrol. The issue was something else in my project not this code

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm trying to resize my tabcontrol using the `tabControl1_Selected` event then `tabControl1.Size = new Size` to change to the new size. When I hover over size it displays the size of the form and not the tabcontrol. I can't work out what to put instead of `new Size` that will change the control not the form.

I got the `new Size` from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.itemsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but their example is more about tabs than the actual control itself.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the issue.  You are hovering your mouse over the Size keyword, so the intellisense is showing the value for this.Size, your form.  Try moving your mouse over the `tabControl1.Size` to the left, then you will see the value of the size of your TabControl.  Code works otherwise.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is resize the tabcontrol. I'm trying to pass the 457, 580 to it as the newsize but the new size holds 485, 801 which as you mention is the form size.

Comment: That's not what happens when I run the code you posted.  My TabControl resizes on every tab select.  Try running *just this code* on a new project.

Comment: You are pretty fatally confused.  Add a watch for "tabControl1.Size" instead.  Fwiw, you should *never* write this kind of code anyway, hard-coding control sizes is something you'll deeply regret when you see what happens when you run your program on a machine with a high DPI video setting.

Comment: @LarsTech I just ran it in a new project and it works exactly how I wanted it to. I best have a look at what the rest of the stuff is doing. Thank you

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the help. It's just practice but I will take note

Answer (score 1):

Check if the new size of your TabControl is overridden by your Dock-Property.

Height & Width will both be overriden by `DockStyle.Fill`.
Width will be overridden by `DockStyle.Top` and `DockStyle.Bottom`.
Height will be overridden by `DockStyle.Left` and `DockStyle.Right`.

Comment: The control isn't docked. Dock is set to None. I removed all controls on the form except for this in case it was a panel or something underneath but it gives the exact same size.

Comment: I think you mix up the initial values of the Size-struct (System.Drawing) and the actual size of your control. It seems you hovered over Size (and that gives you the values 485, 801) at a state of code, where new Size(457, 325) was not yet executed. At this point the Size-struct seems to have the default values of your Winform. Step over it and you will see that it sets the values you pass as parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change. It always displays the form size. I'm fairly sure I'm supposed to have something else instead of just new Size but I haven't as yet been able to work out what.

Comment: Maybe it's the TabControl.MinimumSize, which prevents it from resizing...?

Comment: Stephan. Thanks for your help. I'm sure your suggestions would have worked had I not had other issues that were effecting what this was doing.